# Why the constructor of the subclass is raising error?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
class Superr {
 int k;
 int g;
 int l;

 Superr(int a, int b, int c) {
  k = a;
  g = b;
  l = c;
 }

 void show() {
  System.out.println("value of l" + l);
 }

}

class Sub extends Superr {
 int h;

 Sub(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  e = a;
  f = b;
  g = c;
  l = d;
 }

 class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Superr b = new Super(1, 2, 3);
   Sub c = new Sub(1, 2, 3, 4);
  }
```

Can you help me please to understand why I got error the below error:

constructor super from class super cannot be applied to given types
required: int,int,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: [Questins seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the **desired behavior**, **a specific** problem or **error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: super is a reserved key word. Nobody can use them

Comment: Other than using keyword `super`, the subclass constructor must call a superclass constructor. By default, it will call the no-arg superclass constructor, but you superclass doesn't have a no-src constructor, so you **must** explicitly call a superclass constructor. See [The Java™ Tutorials - **Using the Keyword `super`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), or (re)read the Java guide you're learning from, since this should all be covered there.

Comment: What are `e` and `f`?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

1. There is an implicit call to `super()` at the beginning of the `sub` constructor (i.e. the superclass constructor).  Since you did not provide a constructor in `Superr` that takes no arguments, this causes the error message.  To prevent the error you must either provide a constructor in `Superr` that takes no arguments, or invoke the existing three-argument constructor, as in:

   ```
    Sub(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        super(a,b,c);
        l = d;
     }
   ```
2. You did not declare `e` and `f` anywhere, so this will cause another syntax error.

In future, to avoid confusion, do not call your classes `Superr` and `Sub`.  We can deal with `A` and `B extends A` just fine.

Answer (score -1):

*super* is a keyword you cannot use for a class name.

Comment: consider superr instead of super this is not the main issue.

Comment: "*consider superr instead of super*" - No, please don't. In Java, class names should be written in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (first letter capitalized).

Comment: is it ok now for the question ?

Comment: @Martin.B not really. Your class is named `Superr` (as is the constructor), but `Sub extends Super`.